# Better way to control watching values for Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My environment is Vue CLI 3.11(from Node.js 12.10) and Google Chrome.

I want to write a syntax that ignores the watch under certain conditions. However, I haven't found a good way because Vue.js changes its value slightly differently from JavaScript.

For example, in this code, the value is always recorded because "valuelock" is always false in watch().

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data(){
    return {
      v: null,
      valuelock: false
    };
  },
  mounted(){
    this.valuelock = true;
    this.v = localStorage.getItem("value");
    if(this.v === null) this.v = 0;
    this.valuelock = false;
  },
  watch:{
    v(nv){
      console.log("watch:"+this.valuelock);
      if(this.valuelock == false){
        localStorage.setItem("value", nv);
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm currently dealing with a delay by setTimeout(), but I don't know that this is correct way.

```
  mounted(){
    this.valuelock = true;
    this.v = localStorage.getItem("value");
    if(this.v === null) this.v = 0;

    const t = this;
    setTimeout(()=>{
      t.valuelock = false;
    }, 0);
  },
```

Please tell me if you know a better way to control with realtime value changes for Vue.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to do this without using `watch` at all. Instead you can use a computed property with `get` and `set` to intercept changes.

```js
export default {
  name: 'app',

  data () {
    return {
      rawValue: null
    }
  },

  computed: {
    value: {
      get () {
        return this.rawValue
      },

      set (value) {
        localStorage.setItem('value', value)
        this.rawValue = value
      }
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.rawValue = +localStorage.getItem('value') || 0
  }
}
```

The rest of the code should then access `value`, not `rawValue`, such that changes will be saved.

I've also tweaked the reading of the value out of `localStorage` to be `+localStorage.getItem('value') || 0`. Based on your default value I've assumed that you want to store a number but `localStorage` will store that as a string.

It should also be possible to move the code in `mounted` into the `data` function. e.g.:

```js
data () {
  return {
    rawValue: +localStorage.getItem('value') || 0
  }
}
```

This would also be viable with your original code and would provide an alternative way to solve the problem. If you set the initial value from `localStorage` in `data` it wouldn't trigger the `watch`.